# Get facebook profile link from Facebook Profile Query

Tags: facebook, profile

ok, I am not sure if I can do this, but what I need to do is get the facebook user profile link when the login.

I am using https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html

What I need to know is can I get profile_link from:

```
query: 'SELECT name, pic FROM profile WHERE id=' + FB.getSession().uid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following

```
query: 'SELECT name, pic, url FROM profile WHERE id=' + FB.getSession().uid
```